# Multiple onclick buttons in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm designing my webpage to use onclick functions to pull in data from other web pages and to display that data using iframe.  The code works exactly as intended when I only have one button; however, when I add a second button and subsequent script, both buttons only pull in the data from the second script. How can I set this up so that EITHER button can be selected and return the proper page? Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<div class="section">

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Illustrators</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() 
    {
        var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Illustrators.php");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
    </script>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Tech Writers</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() 
        {
            var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/TechWriters.php");
            document.body.appendChild(x);
        }
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have 2 functions with the same name. You will need to give it a different name or pass parameters to one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem here is that you are defining two differents function with the same name, so the second declaration of the function is overriding the first one, that's why you always get the second script called actually there's only one function (defined two times).

**Solution:**

Actually you are mixing-up things here, you can't have two functions with the same name in one page even if they are in differents script blocks.

And it's better to use only one script block where you define you functions and then call them in your page, this what it should look like:

```html
<script>
  var iframeExists = false;

  function myFunction1() {
    var x
    if (!iframeExists) {
      x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
      iframeExists = true;
    } else {
      x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
    }
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Illustrators.php");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
  }

  function myFunction2() {
    var x;
    if (!iframeExists) {
      x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
      iframeExists = true;
    } else {
      x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
    }
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/TechWriters.php");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
  }
</script>

<div class="section">

  <button onclick="myFunction1()">Illustrators</button>

  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Tech Writers</button>

</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I just edited the code to add a boolean flag to test if the iframe is created which is initialized to false, if it's false we will create the iframe otherwise we will just get it from the document and update it's content.

Comment: I never even looked at defining each function individually.  I was more worried about getting the code to run properly with iframe.  What you're saying makes perfect sense.  I made the changes you suggested and they work well, but I keep getting multiple iframes popping up each time the buttons are clicked.  Is there a way to add a "reset" of some kind there so each click uses the same iframe?

Comment: @Tony Yes of course, it's very simple we just need to add a boolean flag to test if the iframe is already created or not, take a look at my edit for further information.

Comment: I appreciate your help today!  I knew there needed to be an if/else in there somewhere but I obviously didn't set it up right.  I tried setting it up to check the functions against each other, not within each function itself.  I'm curious though how the var iframeExists works,  The element created is IFRAME.  I thought the two had to be the same for the var to work.

Comment: `var iframeExists` is a global variable because it's declared outside the two functions in the global scope so we can use it in the two functions, that's the only mystery :)

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Thanks again for all of your help.  I learned quite a bit about JS today.

Comment: Great, glad it helps, It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are basically like variables in javascript. If you set the variable `myFunction` to a function, and then set `myFunction` to another function, it will overwrite the previous function, which is what is happening here. Simply change the name of the second function, and you're good to go:

```
<div class="section">


<button onclick="myFunction()">Illustrators</button>

<script>


function myFunction() {
var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Illustrators.php");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}

</script>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Tech Writers</button>

<script>

function myFunction2() {
var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/TechWriters.php");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}

</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the second function will overwrite the first one: you can only have one function with a specific name; another cannot be named the same.

Answer (score -1):

juste declare your function once,

```
    <div class="section">


    <button id="button1" onclick="myFunction()">Illustrators</button>
    <button id="button2" onclick="myFunction()">Tech Writers</button>
</div>
<script>

function myFunction() {
var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/TechWriters.php");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}

</script>
```

but with this method, your function will do the same thing for the 2 buttons.
you should add a parameter to your function like this :

```
       function myFunction(type) {
  var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");

  switch (type) {
    case type: 1
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Illustrators.php");   
    break;
    case type : 2
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/TechWriters.php");
    break;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

and call your function in the onclick with the correct parameter